# Emacs cannot load auto-complete package

Tags: emacs, autocomplete

I have Emacs (the latest from the savannah repo) installed, and I used `package-install` to get `auto-complete-20140414.2324`. I then followed (or tried to) the instructions at [this site](http://cx4a.org/software/auto-complete/manual.html#Manual_Installation). Specifically, I added the following to my `.emacs`:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/elpa")
(require 'auto-complete-config)
(add-to-list 'ac-dictionary-directories "~/.emacs.d/elpa/auto-complete-20140414/dict")
(ac-config-default)
```

I know for a fact that those directories are where `auto-complete-20140414` and its dictionary folder respectively are. However, when I boot Emacs, I get the following warning:

```
File error: Cannot open load file, no such file or directory, auto-complete-config
```

There's nothing in the instructions I found about this, and I'm not sure what the issue is. Could someone help me out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your configuration is wrong. You need not to set `load-path` manually for
installed packages with package.el. You just call `package-initialize` as
below. `package-initialize` set `load-path` for all installed package
directories.

```
(package-initialize)

(require 'auto-complete-config)
(add-to-list 'ac-dictionary-directories "~/.emacs.d/elpa/auto-complete-20140414/dict")
(ac-config-default)
```